# Fabric8: Unable to stop the cluster exec: "minikube": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: macos, fabric8

I have fabric8, when I try run

```
gofabric8 stop
```

I got the error message: **Unable to stop the cluster exec: "minikube": executable file not found in $PATH**

I wonder where the minikube is located on OSX El Captan, so I can add it on the PATH.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you installed minikube really. Personally, I just throw the binary under /usr/local/bin, so no need to mess with PATH.

From what I see for OSX the recommended way of installing minikube is via brew:

```
brew cask install minikube
```

which I think that will just throw it under Applications(?).